# Unity and NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, unity-container

I am trying to perform unit test to written method but I am facing issue.

Here is my UnityConfig class:

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterInstance(AutoMapperConfig.Initialize());
        container.RegisterType<IActiveDirectoryUserService, ActiveDirectoryUserService>();
        container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, InMemoryUserRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
    }
}
```

Tested method:

```
public async Task RegisterAsync(string name, string email, string firstName, string lastName, string password)
{
    var user = await _userRepository.GetBynameAsync(name);

    if (user != null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"User {name} already exists.");
    }
    else
    {
        var ActiveDirectoryUser = await _ActiveDirectoryUserService.GetBynameAsync(name);

        if (ActiveDirectoryUser == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"User {name} does not exist in Active Directory");
        }
        else
        {
            var salt = new Guid().ToString("N");
            user = new User(name, ActiveDirectoryUser.Email, ActiveDirectoryUser.FirstName, ActiveDirectoryUser.LastName, password, salt);
            await _userRepository.AddAsync(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    var activeDirectoryUserMock = new Mock<IactiveDirectoryUserService>();
    var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();

    var userService = new UserService(userRepositoryMock.Object, activeDirectoryUserMock.Object, mapperMock.Object);

    await userService.RegisterAsync("name", "user@emial.com", "first name", "last name", "password");

    userRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Tested method works fine outside test but when I run test it fails. I ran test in debug mode and I found that it does not enter to

```
var user = await _userRepository.GetBynameAsync(name);

var ActiveDirectoryUser = await _ActiveDirectoryUserService.GetBynameAsync(name);
```

Any idea why it does not enter to these methods during testing? Do I need add some entries to UnityConfig to make it work?

-- EDIT

```
private static ISet<User> _users = new HashSet<User>
{
    new User("user1", "ab@rmail.com", "firstnam1", "lastname1", "pass", "salt"),
    new User("user2", "ac@rmail.com", "firstnam2", "lastname2", "pass", "salt"),
    new User("user3", "ad@rmail.com", "firstnam3", "lastname3", "pass", "salt")
};

public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllAsync()
    => await Task.FromResult(_users);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that the mocks do not know how to return from an async call so when the code tries to await them it fails. It does not necessarily have to do with your DI container. It is not present in this unit test.

Making some assumptions since not enough information was provided about the types being used in the Test.

Given the method under test, let us assume you have interface like this

```
public interface IUserRepository {
    Task<User> GetByNameAsync(string name);
    Task AddAsync(User user);
}
public interface IActiveDirectoryUserService {
    Task<AdUserAccount> GetByNameAsync(string name);
}
public class AdUserAccount {
    public  string Email { get; set; }
    public  string FirstName { get; set; }
    public  string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Note the methods that return a `Task`.

You would need to setup the mock to know how to handle async calls and allow tasks to flow to completion.

```
[Test]
public async Task Test() {
    //Arrrange
    var name = "name";
    var email = "user@emial.com";
    var firstname = "first name";
    var lastname = "last name";

    var userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    //Testing that it returns no user for that name so return null from async call
    userRepositoryMock.Setup(_ => _.GetByNameAsync(name)).ReturnsAsync((User)null);
    //Need this to make sure async call runs to completion
    userRepositoryMock.Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));

    var activeDirectoryUserMock = new Mock<IActiveDirectoryUserService>();
    //fake account for mock AD call
    var adUser = new AdUserAccount {
        Email = email,
        FirstName = firstname,
        LastName = lastname
    };            
    //Need fake ad account to return from async call
    activeDirectoryUserMock.Setup(_ => _.GetByNameAsync(name)).ReturnsAsync(adUser);

    var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();

    var userService = new UserService(userRepositoryMock.Object, activeDirectoryUserMock.Object, mapperMock.Object);

    //Act
    await userService.RegisterAsync(name, email, firstname, lastname, "password");

    //Assert
    userRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interfaces you assumed looks same as mint. I don't understand two things. For userRepositoryMock why are you calling AddAsync method? Also for adUserMock why you created fake account? Is there any other library which supports async calls so I could write tests in more gentle way?

Comment: @ironcurtain `AddAsync` returns a `Task`. If you do not set it up the mock will not return anything and the method under test wont flow to completion.

Comment: @ironcurtain The same holds for the other dependency. It was not setup properly. In the test the dependencies are being mocked so that the method under test can be tested in isolation without any knock on effect that may arise due to using concrete implementations. The methods being tested are also async so that needs to be taken into consideration when arranging the the test.

Comment: @ironcurtain has this been resolved. I ask because looking at your question history you have a habit of not accepting answers. Last one being in 2014. If this answer resolves your issue consider marking it as the answer so that the post can be considered resolved.

Comment: why are you creating fake account for mock AD call when it is returned by var ActiveDirectoryUser = await _ActiveDirectoryUserService.GetBynameAsync(name); ?

Comment: I had no idea what you were returning there. I made an assumption. Plus if unit testing, you do not want to hit the actual AD so my assumption was that this was a service that could be mocked. As I explained in the answer

Comment: I am trying to understand unit testing. So in case I test if register method was invoked once I need to assume that User does not exist and AD user exists? Also when I will be testing something like regiter_async_existing_user_should_return_exception I need to mock some fake user? In this case I don't need to mock AD user because it is invoked after User is checked against database, am I right? Another test I need to write is register_async_missing_ad_user_should_return_exception and in this case I need to mock null User and null AD user, am I right?

Comment: When unit testing you mock only what is needed to make the code perform the desired behavior. If you do not expect code to reach a particular dependency then no need to set it up. if it is needed to initialize the target then sure create it, but no need to set up any behavior if it is not going to be used.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. One more thing. I commented line"userRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.AddAsync(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));" and test passed. Is this line really required?

Comment: In this particular case, not necessarily but I did it so as to make sure that the async call was awaited properly. In this case if you comment it out it returns null, but I another scenario it may cause problems so I err on the side of caution by making sure async calls actually return a Task.

Comment: Thanks. What in case I have let's say InMemoryADUser repository class where I have defined initial collection of users. Would it be possible to Mock it to the test methods? Also I don't understand why I need to mock fake users while in UnityConfig class I have container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, InMemoryUserRepository>();

Comment: 1) Yes to first question. 2) Unless directly configured to be used, unit test is not using the container. unit test executing in isolation. So as far as the unit test is concerned it knows nothing about the unity container. That is why you are mocking the dependencies.

Comment: I edited my post and added initialization of users in my InMemoryUSerRepository class. Can you please show me how can I mock it to my test class?

Comment: @ironcurtain, not cool. While related, this is a whole new question. Create question with relevant details and link to it. I will help there.

Comment: before I create new question please tell me if this approach is correct or this is an anti pattern?

Comment: Clearly explain the problem and you will get an answer. Is not that the premise of Stackoverflow?

Comment: can we get Mock from nuget?

Comment: @SameeraR. Yes you can add Moq to your Test project via Nuget.